# Search within file, increment version numbers, and save with perl

Tags: perl

I have a file that contains several entries that look like this:

```
        Banana1015 {
            versionName "1.0.2"
            versionCode 4
        }

        BeachRadio {
            versionName "1.0.0"
            versionCode 1
        }

        BIGFROG104 {
            versionName "1.0.3"
            versionCode 4
        }
```

I would like to create a perl script where I can pass a parameter of the entry to search for (i.e. "BeachRadio") in this file, and then it would increment the versionName and versionCode just for that entry, and save the file. It could just increment the 3rd decimal place in versionName as a default, but ideally could pass a parameter that allows for either major, minor, or patch version increment.

What I've got so far just reads the file, and outputs when it finds the "BeachRadio" entry:

```
#!perl -w
$file="build.gradle";

open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    print if /BeachRadio/ .. /}/;
}
```

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that file format, one way is to read by paragraphs. Then each paragraph is read into a string, on which you can use a straight regex. To read paragraphs we set the [input record separator ($/)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles).

The remaining bit is to change values only for those parameters that have been submitted

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my $file = 'build.gradle';
my $section = 'BeachRadio';  # default to test
my ($major, $minor, $patch);  
GetOptions(
    'file=s' => \$file, 'section=s' => \$section, 
    'major=i' => \$major, 'minor=i' => \$minor, 'patch=i' => \$patch,
) or die "Usage: $0 ...";


{ # limit scope of $/ change if there is other code
    local $/ = "\n\n";

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    while (<$fh>) 
    {
        if (/^\s*$section\s*{/)
        { 
            s{versionName\s*"\K(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)}
             {join '.', $major//$1, $minor//$2, $patch//($3+1)}e;   #"

            s/versionCode\s*\K(\d+)/$1+1/e;
        }
        print;  # or write to file
    }
}
```

I use `{}{}` delimiters in regex so that `//` can be used inside without escaping.

The [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) is a particular form of a [positive lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) `(?<=pattern)`, that discards all previous matches. So we don't have to put it all back in the replacement, just the part matched after `\K`.

The replacement side is evaluated as code, due to `/e` modifier. The replacement string is formed by [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)ing by `.` replacements for each number, either its prescribed (if defined) or existing value.  This uses [defined-or `//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) operator. 
The last number is at least incremented by one, the default.

Note that there is no error handling for wrong  file/line format. Please add checks as appropriate.

This prints the expected output in all invocations in my tests.

Comment: It looks good, but I'm getting this error: Use of uninitialized value $_ in print at version_increment.pl line 25, <$fh> line 2055.

Comment: @codeman  Added command-line options via `Getopt::Long`.  Tested in all invocations.

Comment: @codeman Welcome :)  Note that there is no error checking there so the file had better be all as expected.  This is easy to add.  (I'll add a note on this in the answer later.) Also, there is some complexity here -- in the sense that there are a number of components to be aware of, or that can be useful in their own right.  Let me know if they need explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'build.gradle';

my $arg = shift;
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;

if ( $str =~ /^\s*\Q$arg\E\s*{/mg ) {
    if ( $str =~ /\s*versionName\s*"\d+\.\d+\./sg ) {
        my $save_pos = $+[0];
        $str =~ s/\G(\d+)/$1+1/e;
        pos( $str ) = $save_pos;
        $str =~ s/\G\d+"\s*versionCode\s*\K(\d+)/$1+1/se;
    }
    print $str;
}
```

Comment: It printed out the entire file but didnt make a change

Comment: If you mean it didnt change the file: Just redirect the output to a file.. or you could save the output from within the Perl script if you like

Comment: Thanks did that but it didnt increment the versionName for the one I searched.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the `versionCode` but that should be easy